# JAR Selenium files not recognized and test class not running on eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium-webdriver

I already downloaded the selenium folder for java and changed the build path of my project by adding the JAR files but the test is not running:

This is my code:

```
package seleniumTest;

import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

public class Test1 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Documents\\browserdrivers\\chromedriver.exe");
        ChromeDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.get("https://www.google.com");
    }
}
```

and this is the error that I am getting:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/common/io/ByteStreams
    at org.seleniumhq.selenium.remote_driver/org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService$Builder.parseLogOutput(DriverService.java:472)
    at org.seleniumhq.selenium.chrome_driver/org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriverService$Builder.loadSystemProperties(ChromeDriverService.java:257)
    at org.seleniumhq.selenium.remote_driver/org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService$Builder.build(DriverService.java:495)
    at org.seleniumhq.selenium.chrome_driver/org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriverService.createDefaultService(ChromeDriverService.java:137)
    at org.seleniumhq.selenium.chrome_driver/org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:51)
    at seleniumTest/seleniumTest.Test1.main(Test1.java:8)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.common.io.ByteStreams
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:641)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
    ... 6 more
```

Through this code google chrome should have opened

Answer (score 0):

Right click the project --> Select Propertise --> Select JAVA BUILD PATH --> Select 'Order & Export' tab --> Select 'JRE System library' then 'Apply'. After all of that try to run the class[image]

Comment: I did the same thing but it is still not working